# How to reduce duplicate elements in stream and compute count of duplicate without intermediate containers

Tags: set, java-stream, reduce

I have a list of objects that can have duplicates. Each object has a frequency attribute. I need to not only count the number of duplicate but also update the frequency for that unique element.

**Example**

```
class SomeObject {
   private String id;
   private String name;
   private int frequency;
}
```

In pre-stream world I can do this

```
 List<SomeObject> listWithDuplicates;
 Set<SomeObject> uniques = new HashSet<>();
 for(SomeObject someObject: listWithDuplicates) {
    if(uniques.contains(someObject)) {
       SomeObject seen = uniques.get(someObject);
       seen.setFrequency(seen.getFrequency()+1);
    } else {
       someObject.setFrequency(1);
       uniques.add(someObject);
    }
}
```

**Question** - How can i achieve the same result in java 8 stream without creating an intermediate container?

Answer (score 0):

First you will *always* create an intermediate container with or without streams, where are you going to store the intermediate result otherwise?

From a stream perspective I came up with this:

```
Set<SomeObject> set = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> {
        s.setFrequency(1);
        return s;
    }, s -> s, (l, r) -> {
        l.setFrequency(l.getFrequency() + r.getFrequency());
        return l;
    })).keySet();
```

Comment: This lacks the initial initialization of `frequency` to `1` (one). Further, the merge function relies on sequential execution. The correct function would be `l.setFrequency(l.getFrequency() + r.getFrequency()); return l;`, of course, relying on `frequency` being initially assigned to one.

Comment: @Holger I assumed that frequency is always initialized to 1, probably a bad assumption.

Comment: Still not sufficient. If the same instance appears multiple times in the source `list`, your function may reset an already recorded number to one. A direct consequence of violating the non-interference rule. I think, for the `toMap` collector, there is no other solution than initializing the frequency of all elements to one in step preceding the stream operation.

Comment: @Holger :( darn... feel dumb missing that.

Answer (score 0):

Your pre-stream code is inconsistent. It seems you can’t decide whether `uniques` is a `Map` or a `Set`. You can’t do `get(someObject)` on a `Set` and you can’t do `add(someObject)` on a `Map`.

Besides that, it seems to be a common anti-pattern to use an obsolete `contains` or `containsKey` pre-check to do a conditional adding or putting despite these operations are already conditional by definition.

In case of a `Set`, you could do:

```
Set<SomeObject> uniques = new HashSet<>();
for(SomeObject someObject: listWithDuplicates) {
    if(uniques.add(someObject)) someObject.setFrequency(1);
    else someObject.setFrequency(someObject.getFrequency()+1);
}
```

or even simpler

```
Set<SomeObject> uniques = new HashSet<>();
for(SomeObject someObject: listWithDuplicates) {
    someObject.setFrequency(uniques.add(someObject)? 1: someObject.getFrequency()+1);
}
```

Of course, this assumes that equality implies identity, i.e. that `SomeObject` doesn’t have an `equals` implementation that allows distinct instances to be considered equal.

Otherwise, using a `Map` to get the canonical, i.e. first encountered instance is unavoidable:

```
Map<SomeObject, SomeObject> map = new HashMap<>();
for(SomeObject someObject: listWithDuplicates) {
    SomeObject previous = map.putIfAbsent(someObject, someObject);
    if(previous==null) someObject.setFrequency(1);
    else previous.setFrequency(previous.getFrequency()+1);
}
Set<SomeObject> uniques = map.keySet();
```

One way to achieve the same with a Stream is

```
Set<SomeObject> uniques=listWithDuplicates.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.summingInt(x -> 1)),
        map -> {
            map.forEach(SomeObject::setFrequency);
            return map.keySet();
    }));
```